# Firebase Cloud Messaging on iOS: Improving message delay for foreground notifications

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

When sending a message with both `data` and `notification` payload set, they are displayed as usual when the app is in background. However, when the app is in foreground, they are received in

```
UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate userNotificationCenter:willPresentNotification:withCompletionHandler:
```

This works fine so far, but the delay between sending and receiving foreground messages is considerably higher than the one we observed on our android application (which also uses Firebase). The reason seems to be that these notifications are always sent via APNS instead of the persistent Firebase connection.

How can I force Firebase to send messages containing both `data` and `notification` payloads via their own connection instead of APNS when the app is in foreground?

So basically I want them to behave like pure data messages (which are received in `IRMessagingDelegate applicationReceivedRemoteMessage:`) when the app is in foreground and still be able to display a notification if it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't. If there's a `notification` element attached to the message, FCM will always send those through APNs.

Your only option might be to send two messages -- one data only message (which will be sent via FCM when your app is in the foreground) and a notification message (which will be sent via APNs), and have your app handle the case of it receiving both of these messages if its running in the foreground.